# split string in javascript with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have the following string in javascript,

```
Id:121,RefId:123,Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

when i tried to split it into 3 key,value pairs using , as the separator it is giving me wrong out put because in date there is another ,(comma).
So i guess i must use regular expression.
I want to display it as follows;

```
Id:121   
RefId:123   
Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Can anyone please suggest how to overcome the extra comma in date using regular expression?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: “Some people, when faced with a problem think ‘I know; I use regular expressions’. Now they have two problems.”

Comment: How did you got such a string? Its ambiguous format is not easy to handle. Why don't you use JSON, CSV or such?

Comment: @Joey: As both our failed attempts to do it without regexes show, sometimes *not* using a regex causes more problems :)

Comment: Tim: Indeed. Still, the point holds in most cases :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean split on the `,` which is followed not the white space?

```
'Id:121,RefId:123,Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM  '.split(/,(?=\S)/);
// will give you ["Id:121", "RefId:123", "Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM  "]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you really want a regular expression (instead of a limited split) you could do this:

```
var text = "Id:121,RefId:123,Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM";
text.match(/^(.+?),(.+?),(.+)$/);
```

Comment: You could use `[^,]*` instead of `.+?`, that would be a bit more efficient.

Comment: [^,] or .+? would not make any difference in assembly but you can choose what you want.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky I think Tim means the difference of performance.

Comment: it would only make a performance difference if there would be more than one char in [^]

Comment: No, that's not correct. Your regex, applied to the test string, takes the regex engine 49 steps until a match is achieved instead of 10 steps that my regex would take. By making the `+` quantifier lazy, you force the regex engine to backtrack after each character. This is even worse if the input string cannot be matched. If I take out the second and third comma from the string, your regex takes 248 steps to figure out a non-match, mine takes 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use a regular expression, you can try this:

```
re = /^Id:(\d+),RefId:(\d+),Date:(.+)/
matches = re.exec("Id:121,RefId:123,Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM")
matches[1] // "121"
matches[2] // "123"
matches[3] // "Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM"
```